# Yet unknown variables inside array

Tags: php

Is there a way to add some kind of parameters to array (yet unknown variables)? As you can see here, i dont know the userID in advance (before the mysql fetch), so i cant properly form a link leading to edit page.

```
<?php

$box = array ('1'=>"<a href='edit.php?id=/PROBLEM??/'>edit</a>",'2'=>'Cannot edit');


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($something)) {

?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $box[$row["editable"]]; ?></td>
</tr>


<?php

}

?>
```

> $row["editable"] returns 1 or 2, depends on database record which
>   returns if user is editable or not.

Comment: Why not just split the link into a prefix and a postfix, and then if $row["editable"] is 1, echo the prefix, the user ID, and the postfix?

Comment: Build your link after the query.

Comment: This is why we don't mix business logic with html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sprintf()`:

```
$box = array ('1'=>"<a href='edit.php?id=%d'>edit</a>",'2'=>'Cannot edit');

echo sprintf($box[$row["editable"]], ID_HERE)
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way around...

```
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($something)) : ?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>

<?php if( $row["editable"] === 1 ) : ?>
   <td><a href='edit.php?id=<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>'>edit</a></td>
<?php else : ?>
    <td>Cannot edit</td>
<?php endif; ?>

</tr>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$box = array ('1'=>"<a href='edit.php?id=%ID%'>edit</a>",'2'=>'Cannot edit');
$link = str_replace('%ID%', $row["id"], $box[$row["editable"]]);
```